# Zipping a folder/file using Qt

Tags: qt, zip

I would like to know if there is any class in Qt which can zip a folder or file. I used QProcess to compress, it got compressed but I am unable to uncompress it using a normal zip tool. Can anyone let me know how can we compress a folder/file using Qt api classes?

Answer (score 36):

A few years ago I had such a issue, and here is my solution:

1). get QuaZip (here is the [link text](https://stachenov.github.io/quazip/))

2). include quazip sources to your project file

Headers:

```
HEADERS += src/quazip/crypt.h \
           src/quazip/ioapi.h \
           src/quazip/quazip.h \
           src/quazip/quazipfile.h \
           src/quazip/quazipfileinfo.h \
           src/quazip/quazipnewinfo.h \
           src/quazip/unzip.h \
           src/quazip/zip.h \
           ...
```

Sources:

```
SOURCES += src/quazip/ioapi.c \
           src/quazip/quazip.cpp \
           src/quazip/quazipfile.cpp \
           src/quazip/quazipnewinfo.cpp \
           src/quazip/unzip.c \
           src/quazip/zip.c
           ...
```

3). add headers

```
#include "quazip/quazip.h"
#include "quazip/quazipfile.h"
```

4). use extract function:

```
static bool extract(const QString & filePath, const QString & extDirPath, const QString & singleFileName = QString("")) {

QuaZip zip(filePath);

if (!zip.open(QuaZip::mdUnzip)) {
    qWarning("testRead(): zip.open(): %d", zip.getZipError());
    return false;
}

zip.setFileNameCodec("IBM866");

qWarning("%d entries\n", zip.getEntriesCount());
qWarning("Global comment: %s\n", zip.getComment().toLocal8Bit().constData());

QuaZipFileInfo info;

QuaZipFile file(&zip);

QFile out;
QString name;
char c;
for (bool more = zip.goToFirstFile(); more; more = zip.goToNextFile()) {

    if (!zip.getCurrentFileInfo(&info)) {
        qWarning("testRead(): getCurrentFileInfo(): %d\n", zip.getZipError());
        return false;
    }

    if (!singleFileName.isEmpty())
        if (!info.name.contains(singleFileName))
            continue;

    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        qWarning("testRead(): file.open(): %d", file.getZipError());
        return false;
    }

    name = QString("%1/%2").arg(extDirPath).arg(file.getActualFileName());

    if (file.getZipError() != UNZ_OK) {
        qWarning("testRead(): file.getFileName(): %d", file.getZipError());
        return false;
    }

    //out.setFileName("out/" + name);
    out.setFileName(name);

    // this will fail if "name" contains subdirectories, but we don't mind that
    out.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    // Slow like hell (on GNU/Linux at least), but it is not my fault.
    // Not ZIP/UNZIP package's fault either.
    // The slowest thing here is out.putChar(c).
    while (file.getChar(&c)) out.putChar(c);

    out.close();

    if (file.getZipError() != UNZ_OK) {
        qWarning("testRead(): file.getFileName(): %d", file.getZipError());
        return false;
    }

    if (!file.atEnd()) {
        qWarning("testRead(): read all but not EOF");
        return false;
    }

    file.close();

    if (file.getZipError() != UNZ_OK) {
        qWarning("testRead(): file.close(): %d", file.getZipError());
        return false;
    }
}

zip.close();

if (zip.getZipError() != UNZ_OK) {
    qWarning("testRead(): zip.close(): %d", zip.getZipError());
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

and archive function:

```
static bool archive(const QString & filePath, const QDir & dir, const QString & comment = QString("")) {

QuaZip zip(filePath);
zip.setFileNameCodec("IBM866");

if (!zip.open(QuaZip::mdCreate)) {
    myMessageOutput(true, QtDebugMsg, QString("testCreate(): zip.open(): %1").arg(zip.getZipError()));
    return false;
}

if (!dir.exists()) {
    myMessageOutput(true, QtDebugMsg, QString("dir.exists(%1)=FALSE").arg(dir.absolutePath()));
    return false;
}

QFile inFile;

// Получаем список файлов и папок рекурсивно
QStringList sl;
recurseAddDir(dir, sl);

// Создаем массив состоящий из QFileInfo объектов
QFileInfoList files;
foreach (QString fn, sl) files << QFileInfo(fn);

QuaZipFile outFile(&zip);

char c;
foreach(QFileInfo fileInfo, files) {

    if (!fileInfo.isFile())
        continue;

    // Если файл в поддиректории, то добавляем имя этой поддиректории к именам файлов
    // например: fileInfo.filePath() = "D:\Work\Sources\SAGO\svn\sago\Release\tmp_DOCSWIN\Folder\123.opn"
    // тогда после удаления части строки fileNameWithSubFolders будет равен "Folder\123.opn" и т.д.
    QString fileNameWithRelativePath = fileInfo.filePath().remove(0, dir.absolutePath().length() + 1);

    inFile.setFileName(fileInfo.filePath());

    if (!inFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        myMessageOutput(true, QtDebugMsg, QString("testCreate(): inFile.open(): %1").arg(inFile.errorString().toLocal8Bit().constData()));
        return false;
    }

    if (!outFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly, QuaZipNewInfo(fileNameWithRelativePath, fileInfo.filePath()))) {
        myMessageOutput(true, QtDebugMsg, QString("testCreate(): outFile.open(): %1").arg(outFile.getZipError()));
        return false;
    }

    while (inFile.getChar(&c) && outFile.putChar(c));

    if (outFile.getZipError() != UNZ_OK) {
        myMessageOutput(true, QtDebugMsg, QString("testCreate(): outFile.putChar(): %1").arg(outFile.getZipError()));
        return false;
    }

    outFile.close();

    if (outFile.getZipError() != UNZ_OK) {
        myMessageOutput(true, QtDebugMsg, QString("testCreate(): outFile.close(): %1").arg(outFile.getZipError()));
        return false;
    }

    inFile.close();
}

// + комментарий
if (!comment.isEmpty())
    zip.setComment(comment);

zip.close();

if (zip.getZipError() != 0) {
    myMessageOutput(true, QtDebugMsg, QString("testCreate(): zip.close(): %1").arg(zip.getZipError()));
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

5). enjoy ;)

**UPDATE**: for [CapDroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624069/capdroid).

```
/* Рекурсивно ищет все файлы в директории \a и добавляет в список \b */
static void recurseAddDir(QDir d, QStringList & list) {

    QStringList qsl = d.entryList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files);

    foreach (QString file, qsl) {

        QFileInfo finfo(QString("%1/%2").arg(d.path()).arg(file));

        if (finfo.isSymLink())
            return;

        if (finfo.isDir()) {

            QString dirname = finfo.fileName();
            QDir sd(finfo.filePath());

            recurseAddDir(sd, list);

        } else
            list << QDir::toNativeSeparators(finfo.filePath());
    }
}
```

Comment: QuaZip is LGPL, so you must either have your main program in a license compatible with LGPL (LGPL or GPL for example) or distribute the QuaZip library as a separate dynamic library file and not include any of its code statically in your program.

Comment: If you simply skip folders, QuaZip won't be able to list them when you try extracting your zip. You need to create an empty file with name ending with "/". See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24517029/1385405

Comment: Consider to use `include(thirdParty/quazip/quazip.pri)` and `LIBS += -lz` to import QuaZip to your Qt project.

Comment: In the recurseAddDir() you 'return' if a file isSymLink() is true. Wouldn't you want to 'continue' instead? The first SymLink you run into will make you skip all other files in the directory.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can. As far as I know qcompress and quncompress only provide compressing of streams etc. This means they will not create the headers needed for a real zipfile (which also say which files are in the file).

However there is an open source Qt library called [QuaZip](http://quazip.sourceforge.net/) which uses zlib (comes with qt) and provides just that.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Qt 5.12 version.

In pro file, add "QT += gui-private".

In the cpp file, example:

```
#include "QtGui/private/qzipreader_p.h"
#include "QtGui/private/qzipwriter_p.h"

......


QFileInfoList list = getFileList(zipPath);//zipPath
QZipWriter writer(zipFile);
if(list.size()<=0){
    qDebug()<<"there is no file to zip, please check it";
    return false;
}
//
for(int i=0;i != list.size(); i++){
    QString filename=list.at(i).filePath();
    qDebug()<<"filename:"<<filename.mid(pos+1);
    QFile file(filename);
    if(file.exists()){
        file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        writer.addFile(filename.mid(pos+1), file.readAll());
        file.close();
    }
    else{
        qDebug()<<"file not exist:"<<filename;
    }
}
writer.close();
```

Comment: so sketchy. i love it.

Answer (score 0):

https://libzip.org/license/ has BSD licence you can use it anywhere

Example (On Linux)
In `.pro` file:

```
HEADERS +=  /usr/include/zip.h

LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lzip

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzip/include headers
```

Function that zip file:

```
int PutFileIntoZip(const QString &filePath)
{
    QFile regFile(filePath);
    Q_ASSERT(regFile.exists());
    const bool canOpenRegFile=regFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    if(canOpenRegFile)
    {
        QString fileNameExpansion=filePath.section(QDir::separator(),-1,-1);
        const QStringRef fileName(&fileNameExpansion, 0, fileNameExpansion.length()-4);//22222.bin -> 22222
        int errorFlagCreateZip = 0;
        const QString zipPath=QDir::homePath()+QDir::separator()+fileName + ".zip";
        zip*const  zipHandle = zip_open(zipPath.toLatin1().constData(), ZIP_CREATE, &errorFlagCreateZip);
        if (ZIP_ER_OK==errorFlagCreateZip)
        {
            FILE* const fileC = fdopen(regFile.handle(), "r");
            zip_source* const  source = zip_source_filep(zipHandle, fileC, 0, regFile.size());
            if (source!=nullptr)
            {
                const zip_int64_t result = zip_file_add(zipHandle, fileNameExpansion.toLatin1().constData(), source, ZIP_FL_OVERWRITE);
                if (result>=0)
                {
                    zip_set_file_compression(zipHandle, result, ZIP_CM_DEFLATE64, 0);
                    qDebug()<< "Done";
                }
                else
                {
                    zip_source_free(source);
                }
            }
            int result = zip_close(zipHandle);
            fclose(fileC);
            regFile.close();
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            zip_error_t error;
            zip_error_init_with_code(&error, errorFlagCreateZip);
            const int zipCreationErrorCode = zip_error_code_zip(&error);
            regFile.close();
            return zipCreationErrorCode;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<< regFile.errorString();
        return -1;
    }
}
```